# List with arrays into seperate arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, list, int

I have a constructor which uses a List parameter. Inside that list I have three items which are 3 integer arrays.

```
public HistogramLogic(List<Tuple<int[], int[], int[]>> separateRGB)
```

Now I want to initialize three new integer arrays with the arrays inside that list. But when I try this code, the index of my new arrays stay 0.

```
for (int i = 0; i < histogramXValues.Length; i++)
{
     rArray = separateRGB.Select(obj => obj.Item1[i]).ToArray();
     gArray = separateRGB.Select(obj => obj.Item2[i]).ToArray();
     bArray = separateRGB.Select(obj => obj.Item3[i]).ToArray();
}
```

Anyone got any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the index of my new arrays stay 0". Do you mean the `Count`?

Comment: @johnWu I mean the length of the new arrays

Comment: Your loop will repeatedly re-assign the values to `rArray`, `gArray`, and `bArray`, overwriting previous values.

Comment: Also the declaration of `separateRGB` seems a bit unusual, I would expect a `List<Tuple<int, int, int>>` or `Tuple<int[], int[], int[]>` for a list of colors, but you probably have a list of lists of colors, and you are trying to effectively extract the values from the second index into an array?

Comment: @kajacx It's definitely a List filled with multiple integer arrays. My purpose is to draw a histogram of the seperate R, G, B values from a random selected picture. So I run through every pixel, inside that pixel I select the seperate R, G, and B values. An IF-statement (inside a for-loop) will check if the R, G  and B value is equal to one of my X-axis values (0-255). If so, it will increment +1. When finished going through all of the pixels. I will set the Y-axis incremented values for R, G and B inside the list (as seperate int arrays) and pass it on to my drawing class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear in mind, if you have a list of N tuples, you start with 3 x N arrays. Sounds like you want them combined into 3 arrays, each containing all of the elements throughout the list. Which you can do with `SelectMany`.

```
rArray = separateRGB.SelectMany(obj => obj.Item1).ToArray();
gArray = separateRGB.SelectMany(obj => obj.Item2).ToArray();
bArray = separateRGB.SelectMany(obj => obj.Item3).ToArray();
```

Full example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    static public void HistogramLogic(List<Tuple<int[], int[], int[]>> separateRGB)
    {
        var rArray = separateRGB.SelectMany(obj => obj.Item1).ToArray();
        var gArray = separateRGB.SelectMany(obj => obj.Item2).ToArray();
        var bArray = separateRGB.SelectMany(obj => obj.Item3).ToArray();

        Console.WriteLine("rArray = {{{0}}}", string.Join(",", rArray));
        Console.WriteLine("gArray = {{{0}}}", string.Join(",", gArray));
        Console.WriteLine("bArray = {{{0}}}", string.Join(",", bArray));
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var mockData = new List<Tuple<int[], int[], int[]>>
        {
            Tuple.Create(new[] {11,12,13}, new[] {14,15,16}, new[] {17,18,19}),
            Tuple.Create(new[] {21,22,23}, new[] {24,25,26}, new[] {27,28,29}),
            Tuple.Create(new[] {31,32,33}, new[] {34,35,36}, new[] {37,38,39})
        };

        HistogramLogic(mockData);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
rArray = {11,12,13,21,22,23,31,32,33}
gArray = {14,15,16,24,25,26,34,35,36}
bArray = {17,18,19,27,28,29,37,38,39}
```

[Click here for code on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bymcLj)

Comment: why you need a `SelectMany()` here?

Comment: Because there is one array per item in the List. This will combine those into one big array.

Comment: @JohnWu Thanks! This helped me out! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You can just get the item from touple

```
rArray = separateRGB.Select(obj => obj.Item1);
```

Comment: This was my initial code, but gave me an error. My problem is fixed though! But thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

Like they sad in comments you did reassign local member in each loop.
You could use something like this.

```
public HistogramLogic(List<Tuple<int[], int[], int[]>> separateRGB)
{
    List<int> rList = new List<int>();
    List<int> gList = new List<int>();
    List<int> bList = new List<int>();

    separateRGB.ForEach((Tuple<int[], int[], int[]> tpl) =>
    {
        rList.AddRange(tpl.Item1);
        gList.AddRange(tpl.Item1);
        bList.AddRange(tpl.Item1);

    });

    rArray = rList.ToArray();
    gArray = gList.ToArray();
    bArray = bList.ToArray();

}
```

If you wish to not use temp List object you should know final count of elements in tuple, create local array member to desired size. and fill it. List are more suitable for adding and expanding elements. Maybe you could use one Linq Statement but if I understand goal is to get one int[] array per color. If you take

```
separateRGB.AsQueryable().Select(m => m.Item1).ToArray();
```

as a result you get int[][] result instead of simple int array;

Comment: I fixed it by using JohnWu's code. Thanks for your help and time! Much appreciated!